# Kendo UI Alternative to MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I have successfully developed a simple grid using MVC 4 and kendo UI. Everything works as expected and I dont have an issue with it. The other day, I was talking to another developer who told me that I could completely bypass MVC and just use a Javascript to read from SQL Server(my data source) and call it on my HTML page. There, I could use Kendo UI helpers to display the page the way I wanted.

My question is, is that possible? And if it is possible, is it advisable? I primarily work only with databases and this is the first time I am playing with MVC, Kendo and HTML as such, so please bear with me.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your colleague is absolutely right. You can use the client version of Kendo UI and write jQuery code on HTML/.cshtml/aspx... files  and connect to your MVC/Web API controllers or a RESTFul/HTTP service using Ajax calls. This will work like a charm.

This is advisable only if you are good with Javascript/jQuery. This method will provide better user experience and you can easily build Single Page Applications which is the future of web apps.

if you see Kendo UI demos, all the examples are built on pure HTML pages using jQuery.

I hope I answered your question clearly, but in case you need any clarifications, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you know of any demo that does this trick? The ones on Kendo UI Website use static data and I really dont want that. Thats what I havent been able to find out yet.

Comment: Checkout this demo: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/remote-data.html . The grid gets data from a remote service with url : http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders . Basiclaly you need to build a service which will return JSON data to your front end. ASP.NET Web API will be your best bet for this: http://www.asp.net/web-api